# Windows 10: Using Task Scheduler to run a VBScript file?

Tags: windows-10, vbscript, task-scheduler

I am migrating over from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

In 7, I ran a VBS file through Task Scheduler that shut down Microsoft Outlook in order to prepare the .pst file for nightly backup. I want to do the same thing in 10, so I imported the task I'd written for 7 into the version of 10.

Thing is, when the task comes due, instead of simply running the script, I get the dialog pop-up asking "How do you want to open this file?" showing choices like Acrobat Reader, Internet Explorer, Notepad, Paint, etc. After a period of no decision it simply aborts the task.

When I click on the VBS file within the folder it located, it closes my open Outlook process, so I know the script works. I just need to provide which "program" Task Scheduler needs to execute it.

Can anyone tell me what missing link I need to provide to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

In the past what has worked for me was calling the VBS file from a batch file, a little bit round about but deployed on ~70 computers without fail.

Create a new batch file, all it needs is "cscript.exe Your_Outlook_Shutdown_Script.vbs", save it and modify your Task Action to launch the batch file instead of the VBS directly.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after much trial and error I figured out how to get this to work.
The main problem I was running into was that I followed your exact text for the batch file which you have as:

```
"cscript.exe Your_Outlook_Shutdown_Script.vbs"
```

Which made the task fail, but when I finally got the bright idea to change it to:

```
cscript.exe "Your_Outlook_Shutdown_Script.vbs"
```

Moving the open quote marks, that's when it finally worked.
Thank you for putting me on the right path.